permutation of indices in tensor notation
I have probably a stupid question. Somehow tensor notation often confuses me. Let's say we have the following equality:
$$f_{ijk}=g_{ijml}\epsilon_{mlk}.$$
Does this imply $g_{ijml}=-g_{ijlm}$? Permuting two indices of the Levi-Civita symbol introduces a minus sign, since the indices $m$ and $l$ don't appear on the LHS of the equation, then clearly this permutation must have no effect on the RHS. I suppose for the sum to be properly carried out as designed, ie. it is the indices $mlml$ appearing and not $mllm$, you also have to permute the indices in $g_{ijml}$, hence $g_{ijml}=-g_{ijlm}$? In my specific case I am a bit surprised that for $l=m$ the coefficients are zero, but I guess that is another matter.

Did you mean for the repeated indices to indicate the summation notation convention? Usually, that is denoted with both lowered and raised indices. I don't understand why you're mentioning $mlml$ or $mllm$. Anyway, the antisymmetry of $\epsilon$ and re-indexability of sums imply $g_{ijml}\epsilon_{mlk}=g_{ijlm}\epsilon_{lm}=-g_{ijlm}\epsilon_{mlk}$. If you could "equate coefficients" of $\epsilon_{mlk}$ this would imply $g_{ijml}=-g_{ijlm}$, but you can't do that. The $\epsilon$s are just a bunch of $\pm1$s and $0$s: it'd be like saying $a+b=-(c+d)$ implies $a=-c$ and $b=-d$.

Ah ok, that was my mistake...

Your question is not very clear.
You can split your tensor into symmetric and non-symmetric parts:
$$
\begin{align}
a_{ijml}&=\left(g_{ijml}+g_{ijlm}\right)/2 \\
b_{ijml}&=\left(g_{ijml}-g_{ijlm}\right)/2 \\
g_{ijml}&=a_{ijml}+b_{ijml}
\end{align}
$$
Then you will get:
$$
g_{ijml}\epsilon_{mlk}=b_{ijml}\epsilon_{mlk}=f_{ijk}
$$
So your $f_{ijk}$ only depends on the part of $g$ that is anti-symmetric with respect to exchange of last two indices.

I see. In principle you could extract $b_{ijml}$ from $f_{ijk}$ by multiplying both sides of your last equation by $\epsilon_{kno}$?
